# How can apply screen effects on Raspberry Pi 3 (with Raspbian)?

Tags: python, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

i am involved in a project with a Rasberry Pi 3 in where the people have to look at a screen reflected by a mirror and interact. The image is inverted so that i wanted to create a program in python to solve this problem. I don´t know where to start because i am new with Raspberry Pi and the Raspbian OS.

Comment: you should probably start by getting a rpi .... and maybe look at the pygame library ... or maybe kivy

Comment: I want to apply to the whole screen since the raspbian OS starts

Answer (score 0):

1) **X.Org**

If you want everything that is displayed by X Window System (X.Org) to be flipped, you can use `xrandr` command.

`xrandr -y` will mirror the display (flip the image vertically).
`xrandr -o normal` will return the display to the default.

2) **Python**

If you write a program in Python that will display some images and you want to flip this images in your program then you can use the [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/3.4.2) module.

Here is a snippet that inverts an image named `cat.jpg` vertically and saves it into `vertical_flip_cat.jpg`:

```
from PIL import Image

my_image = Image.open('cat.jpg')
my_image.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM).save('vertical_flip_cat.jpg')
```

[Here is an overview of the Pillow module with examples.](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter17/)

Comment: OH thanks, how can i apply this to the whole screen since the raspbian OS starts? SHould i have to modify the X.org graphical server?

Comment: @JoanbelkGA Probably, you should describe in more detail what you are doing, where the image that should be inverted comes from and so on.